# Spring Boot is not creating Tables automatically in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I am new to Spring boot and just trying to create the tables using hibernate in spring boot but Unable to do so. Below are my code and configurations

User.java (Entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String first_name;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private boolean enabled = true;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rafey</groupId>
    <artifactId>examback</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>examback</name>
    <description>backend for exam portal.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties file

```
#database configuration

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/examportal
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.datasource.driver-class = com.cj.jdbc.Driver
#JPA configuration
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true 
spring.jpa.open-in-view
```

these are the logs

```
2022-09-05 03:21:44.420  INFO 5320 --- [           main] com.rafey.examback.ExambackApplication   : Starting ExambackApplication using Java 11.0.16 on Abdur-PC with PID 5320 (C:\Users\Rafey\Desktop\examportal\examback\examback\target\classes started by Rafey in C:\Users\Rafey\Desktop\examportal\examback\examback)
2022-09-05 03:21:44.427  INFO 5320 --- [           main] com.rafey.examback.ExambackApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-09-05 03:21:45.676  INFO 5320 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-05 03:21:45.714  INFO 5320 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-09-05 03:21:47.194  INFO 5320 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-09-05 03:21:47.216  INFO 5320 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-09-05 03:21:47.216  INFO 5320 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-09-05 03:21:47.539  INFO 5320 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-05 03:21:47.540  INFO 5320 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2992 ms
2022-09-05 03:21:47.934  INFO 5320 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-09-05 03:21:48.018  INFO 5320 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-09-05 03:21:48.270  INFO 5320 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-09-05 03:21:48.417  INFO 5320 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-09-05 03:21:48.996  INFO 5320 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-09-05 03:21:49.019  INFO 5320 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-09-05 03:21:49.391  INFO 5320 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-09-05 03:21:49.416  INFO 5320 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-09-05 03:21:50.098  INFO 5320 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-09-05 03:21:50.114  INFO 5320 --- [           main] com.rafey.examback.ExambackApplication   : Started ExambackApplication in 6.728 seconds (JVM running for 7.678)
```

This is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication    
public class ExambackApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExambackApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

help me resolving this issue. Thanks

Comment: Please consider searching for: "flyway spring boot example". Actually there are two solutions for that - mentioned flyway, and liquibase...

Comment: you do not need flyway or liquibase to create the tables at startup, so the above comment is incorrect. Could you please enable debug logs so we can see those. Could you please try adding `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` to the properties file

Comment: @Toerktumlare it is working when I moved the Entity class to same package where my main class is but not working for other packages could you help me with that I tried `@EntityScan` but still not working for me.

Comment: please define what "other packages" are. Show us our package structure... i have no idea what "other packages" are.

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare was able to resolve that.